# Insert document with string containing line breaks to mongo using mongo shell

Tags: mongodb, newline, mongo-shell

I am trying to insert the following document into a mongo collection:

```
[
  {
    "text": "tryng to insert a string
with some line breaks",
  }
]
```

By running `db.myCollection.insertMany(documentArray)` where documentArray is just me copy-pasting this array.

But I am getting this error:

```
> db.myCollection.insertMany([
...   {
...     "text": "tryng to insert a string
uncaught exception: SyntaxError: "" literal not terminated before end of script :
@(shell):3:37
> with some line breaks",
uncaught exception: SyntaxError: missing ( before with-statement object :
@(shell):1:5
>   }
uncaught exception: SyntaxError: expected expression, got '}' :
@(shell):1:0
> ]
```

Which obviously appears because it detects the new line character as the end of the command, so Mongo shell thinks it has to run the command, which is not complete.

Is there any way of saving `\r\n` and `\n` characters in MongoDB? Should I use another method not directly with the shell?

Both Mongo and the shell are version 4.4.15

Comment: Well, didn't manage to do it, so for now I am adding the escaped `\n` to the strings instead of adding them with the proper line breaks. Then when retrieving I substitute `\\n` for `\n`

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this instead. The key is to embed the newline character in the string.

```
[
  {
    "text": "trying to insert a string\n" +
"with some line breaks",
  }
]
```

Comment: Doing this is not a possiblity for me. Is there any other way to load a string with linebreaks? I tried with MongoImport but got this error: `Failed: error processing document #1: invalid character '\n' in string literal`

Comment: Also, I think running a command like insertMany, with the array you provided, just adds the string `\n` to the text, not the actual character EOL \n or \x0A